# Creating a single line with a colored image and different colored text (HTML)

Tags: html, colors

I'm trying to create a single line with a colored image used as a bullet point, with a different colored text font. I've been able to successfully create the single line with a single color (lines 1 & 2), and 2 lines with the correct colors (line 3). Here's the code that I have currently:

```
<p style="color: #14abd0;"><i class="fas fa-gem" style="font-size: 24px;"><strong> <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0592/6843/2069/files/Blue_Dimond_1_16x16.png?v=1644231309" width="16x16" height="16x16" style="float: none;"></strong></i> Promotes lean muscle growth</p>

<p style="color: #14abd0;"><i class="fas fa-gem" style="font-size: 24px;"><strong> <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0592/6843/2069/files/Blue_Dimond_1_16x16.png?v=1644231309" width="16x16" height="16x16" style="float: none;"></strong></i> Aids in post-workout recovery</p>

<span><p style="color: #14abd0;"><i class="fas fa-gem" style="font-size: 24px;"><strong> <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0592/6843/2069/files/Blue_Dimond_1_16x16.png?v=1644231309" width="16x16" height="16x16" style="float: none;"></strong></i></p></span><p style="color: #666565;"> Easily digestable</p>
```

[Output of the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a92K8.png)

So as you can see, the last line shows how I want the colors to look, but I can't figure out how to get them to appear on the same line. I'm not a coder/developer by trade, so this is somewhat new to me.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

P tag is creating a new line. Put the style in the span tag for elements you want to keep inline.

```
<p style="font-size: 24px;">
  <span class="fas fa-gem" >
    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0592/6843/2069/files/Blue_Dimond_1_16x16.png?v=1644231309" width="16x16" height="16x16" style="float: none; color: #14abd0;">
  </span>
  <span style="color: #666565;"> Easily digestable</span>
</p>
```